# Proving $n \leq 3^{n/3}$ for $n \geq 0$ via the Well-Ordering Principle

Tags: proof-writing, induction, natural-numbers

I'm attempting to prove:
$$n \leq 3^{n/3} \quad \text{for }n \geq 0$$

I'm having a little trouble continuing. This is what I have so far:

> Suppose for a contradiction there is a subset of nonnegative integers $S$ such that $x > 3^{x/3}$ for $x \in S$. By the Well-Ordering Principle, there is some least element $m \in S$. It also means that for some $n < m$, $n \leq 3^{n/3}$ must apply, and since $n = 0$ holds we can conclude that $m > 0$. If follows that $m - 1 \geq 0$ and so $m - 1 \leq 3^{(m-1)/3}$ applies:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> m - 1 \leq 3^{(m-1)/3} &\equiv (m-1)^3 \leq 3^{m-1} \\
> &\equiv 3(m-1)^3 \leq 3^m \\
> &\equiv 3(m-1)^3 \leq 3^m < m \\
> &\equiv 3(m-1)^3 < m
> \end{align}
> $$

But I'm not sure how to show now that this is a contradiction. How do I continue?

Comment: So the question *requires* you to solve this by the WOP?

Comment: @Boshu I'm attempting some MIT OCW problems and it specifies WOP. I agree it would be a lot easier with simple induction.

Comment: Can't we do this, then: go ahead with your $m$ as you have, and you have the inequality $m\geq3^{\frac{m}{3}}\Rightarrow m3^{-\frac{1}{3}}\geq3^{\frac{m-1}{3}}$. But $3^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ is something close to $0.7$, and then you should have a contradiction on the minimality of $m$, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Made some formatting errors, sorry about that. Should be readable now.

Comment: @Boshu Sorry if this seems a little naive, but what do you mean by contradiction on the minimality of $m$?

Comment: There's a chance that I'm making a mistake here because I haven't slept in some time, so don't take my word for it and correct me if I'm wrong. But by the WOP, $m$ is the least integer for which $n\geq3^{\frac{n}{3}}$. However, if $m3^{-\frac{1}{3}}\geq3^{\frac{m-1}{3}}$, then the fact that $m-1\geq m3^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ should give a contradiction, right?

Comment: After the last line, we have $m\in \{1, 2\}$. More specifically $S=\{1, 2\}$. But, manually show that, for $1$ and $2$ the first inequality holds. So no such set exists.

Comment: @Boshu Thanks for your help, but I'm still having a hard time understanding where you're getting $m - 1 \geq m 3^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Solve the inequality. Check what range you get for this to be false. Check the original hypothesis in that set; it shouldn't be too large.

Comment: @Boshu I got it. Thanks!

Comment: where does the `< m` assumption come from? I'm having a hard time to figure this out.

Comment: @JonathanBeber So I assumed for a contradiction that there are SOME $k \geq 0$ that satisfy the opposite condition, namely $k > 3^{k/3}$. If we can show this leads to a contradiction we can conclude that for ALL $k \geq 0$ that $k \leq 3^{k/3}$ as desired.   So by the Well-Ordering Principle, then of the set $S$ of $k$'s that satisfy $k > 3^{k/3}$, there is some least $m \in S$. Since it's least, then another smaller element $n < m$ outside $S$ must satisfy the opposite condition $n \leq 3^{n/3}$ (otherwise it'd be in $S$ and be least!)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @Andrew Li. I understand that, and I think I'm comfortable with the WOP way of doing this proof since I'm coming from the OCW text book too. What I couldn't understand is how n < m becomes 3^m < m somehow. I tried to express myself better here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979260/proving-n-leq3n-3-for-n-geq0-via-the-well-ordering-principle-2/3979277

Comment: @JonathanBeber Oh! Since $m$ is least element of $S$, so it satisfies $m > 3^{m/3}$ by assumption. The $n$ is useful to establish $m>0$ and $m-1 \geq 0$. The latter condition is useful because we know $m-1$ is outside of $S$.

Comment: Sorry for my slowness, I think I'm too long on this question and my brain is refusing to think it trough. So we have that:

$m>3^{m/3}$

and by consequence:

$m^3>3^m$

but it is still not clear to me why  $3^m<m$

Comment: @JonathanBeber that's actually my fault (I misread my own work!) I can't think off the top of my head what was going on in my head. I've upvoted your question--hopefully it gets a satisfactory answer. Sorry I'm not able to help!

Comment: Thanks for putting effort on answering me here!

Comment: @JonathanBeber Actually, I think that's just plain wrong on my part. I probably did the same thing wrong then as I just did now (misread $m$ as $m/3$). But I don't think rvbarreto's answer depends on my faulty premise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118264/discussion-between-jonathan-beber-and-andrew-li).

Comment: @AndrewLi The postal example from the MIT series hold some clue to this problem (also there is a hint in this problem suggesting _Verify (1) for n  4 by explicit calculation._). I am also inexperienced, but I try this way: Prove cases 1 to 4 explicitly (use calculator to verify) and show that least element _m_ in the set of counterexamples _C_ > 4. Then take m-4 which lies outside _C_ (as m is the least element in a set of +ve integers) and write m-4 <= 3^(m-4)/3. Add 4 to both sides and we have m < 4 + 3^(m-4)/3. Adding 4 to a +ve number gives a number g.t. 4, so we have a contradiction.

Comment: this is the [problem set](https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/assets/courseware/v1/432a6320bb11c2bfba8ed2a47e68f86d/asset-v1:OCW+6.042J+2T2019+type@asset+block/MIT6_042JS15_ps1.pdf) (for those who are interested) and [postal example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1HpgnWQI7I)

Answer (score 3):

Using contradiction, if there exist a $n \ge 0 $ such that

$$
\begin{align}
n &> 3^{n/3}
\end{align}
$$

Then, because of the WOP, there will be a $n=m$ which is the least value of the set that satisfies the inequality above.

It is verifiable that $n \le 3^{n/3}$ holds true for $0 \le n \le 4$. Thus, $m \ge 5$

since $m-3 \lt m$

$$
\begin{align}
(m-3) &\le 3^{(m-3)/3}
\end{align}
$$

Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
(m-3) &\le 3^{m/3}\cdot3^{-1}\\
3(m-3) &\le 3^{m/3}
\end{align}
$$

It is known that $m \lt 3(m-3)$ for any $m \ge 5$, thus

$$
\begin{align}
 m \lt 3(m-3) &\le 3^{m/3}\\
 m &\lt 3^{m/3}
\end{align}
$$

Which contradicts the premise $n > 3^{n/3}$.

Comment: great! This should be chosen as correct answer. But still wondering, whether the foll. reasoning is also OK...After proving cases m=1,2,3,4 manually, least element in set of counterexamples are greater than 4, we had reasoned.  Then take m-4 which lies outside C (as m is the least element in a set of +ve integers) and write $(m-4) \leq 3^ {(m-4)/3}$. Add 4 to both sides and we have $m \leq 4 + 3^ {(m-4)/3}$. Adding 4 to a +ve number gives a number g.t. 4. But we had started with a premise that m > 4, so we have a contradiction. Not sure whether there is a fallacy somewhere....

Comment: You don't need to use m-4, you can use m-3 which makes it much easier to compute. Even if you prove cases only for n=0,1 and 2, that is enough to say that m is equal or greater than 3 and therefore use m-3.

Answer (score 2):

From
$3(m-1)^3 < m$
we get
$3m^3-9m^2+8m-3 < 0$
or
$m(3m^2-9m+8) < 3
$
or
$m(3m(m-3)+8) < 3
$.

This is false for
$m \ge 4$
since
$3m(m-3) \ge 3m \ge 12$.
It is also false for $m=3$
by direct computation.

For a more general
non-inductive proof,
you can use the fact that
$x^{1/x}$ is decreasing for
$x \ge e$
so
$e \le a < b$
implies that
$a^{1/a} > b^{1/b}$
or
$a^b > b^a$
or
$a^{b/a} > b$.

Now put $a = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

By some explicit calculation, you can see that the inequality holds for $m \leq 2$ which means that that the minimum value of that set of contradictions, $m$ has to be greater than 2.

$3(m-1)^{3} < m$, which is implied by your original assumption does not hold for any $m \geq 2$. There is the contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Let C be the set C ::= {$ n \in N | n > 3^{n/3} $}

For the purpose of obtaining contradiction we assume that C is not empty

There is the smallest element $n_0 \in C$

$n_0 \geq 4$ since for n = 3 property holds

We have : $n_0 - 1 \leq 3^{{(n_0 - 1)}/3}$

$3(n_0 - 1)^3 \leq 3^{n_0} < n_0^3$

Draw the graph of the equation : $3(n_0 - 1)^3 - n_0^3= 0$. We have that for all $n \geq 4$ $3(n_0 - 1)^3 - n_0^3 > 0 $

$->$ contradicting the fact so C is empty.