# Proving $n\leq3^{n/3}$ for $n\geq0$ via the Well-Ordering Principle [2]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, natural-numbers, well-orders

I know this question was already asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013815/proving-n-leq-3n-3-for-n-geq-0-via-the-well-ordering-principle/), but it was never marked as answered and all the solutions base themselves on the fact that $3(m-1)^3 < m$, what comes from assuming $3^m < m$ and it's not clear to me.

I tried multiple ways to understand why this assumption was made, but I can't figure it out. My first assumption was that since $m \in S$ it's true that:

$m > 3^{m/3}$

and by consequence:

$m^3 > 3^{m}$

but it still does not prove $3^m < m$. Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: There are two ways to do a well ording proof.  You can show $P(1)$ is true and that $\lnot P(n)\implies \lnot P(n-1)$. And that means no first element where $\lnot P(n)$ can exist so by WOP $P(n)$ is always true.  That basically induction by contrapositive.  The other way is if $P(1)$ is true and any $P(k)$ is false there must be a *first* case where $P(n)$ is false but $P(n-1)$ is true.  So if we can show $P(1)$ and $P(n-1)$ and $\lnot P(n)$ is impossible, we are done.  Assuming $(n-1)\le 3^{\frac {n-1}3}$ but $n > 3^{\frac n3}$ will work *very* nicely here.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was getting confused with the previous example/question where $3^m < m$ was being considered instead of $m > 3^{m/3}$ and by consequence $m^3 > 3^m$. Your answer works just perfectly and I accepted it as the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The well ordering principle comes into play in trying to find the *first* $n$ where $n^3 > 3^n$.

We know $1^3 < 3^1$.

But can there be any $n^3 > 3^n$?

If so, there must be a *first* $n$ where $n^3 > 3^n$. But if $n$ is the *first* then it must be that  $(n-1)^3 \le 3^{n-1}$.

Now hopefully we will be able to show $(n-1)^3 \le 3^{n-1}$ while $n^3 > 3^n$ can't ever happen which means we can never have a first case where $k^3 \le 3^k$ is not true, which means $k^3 \le 3^k$ always will be true.

So multiplying both sides by $3$ we have$3(n-1)^3 \le 3^n$. But we also have $3^n < n^3$.  So $3(n-1)^3 \le 3^n < n^3$.

And $3(n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n -1) < n^3$.

Well now simplify that and

$2n^3 - 9n^2 + 9n - 3< 0$ so

$2n^3 +9n < 9n^2 + 3$.

$2n + \frac 9n < 9 + \frac 3{n^2}$.

So $2n < 2n + \frac 9n < 9 + \frac 3{n^2} $.

If $n \ge 2$ then $\frac 3{n^2} < 1$ and so we either have $n =1$ or $2n < 9+\frac 3{n^2}< 9+1 = 10$.  In any event we must have $n < 5$ or in other words, $n=1,2,3,$ or $4$.

So we test that $n=1,2,3,4$ and get $1^3 < 3^1; 2^3 =8 < 9 =3^2; 3^3 = 3^3; 4^3=64 < 81 = 3^4$.  so none of *those* are the first exception.

So the first exception can not exist.

And if there can't be a *first* value, there can't be *any* value.

Comment: thank you so much for this very clear answer, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It might be more clear to make explicit that the set of solutions are natural numbers, and you've shown there is not a smallest solution, contradicting the well-ordering principle (instead using the term "first", and your confusing phrasing near the bottom). In either case, $+1$.

Comment: @fleablood $3(n^3−3n^2+3n−1)<n^3$ should be $2n^3−9n^2+9n−3<0$ instead of $-1$. I dont think it changes the proof that much, since it's proved by explicit calculation later that $n > 5$, so $9+\frac 1{n^2} < 10$ anyway. What do you think?

Comment: Mathematical errors.  I make 'em.  Doesn't change the gist of the proof but does changes the mechanics and potentially could invalidate the prove..  say as a result we got $n < 6$ and we never check $n=5$ and it turns out that $n=5$ is the first exception.... then my proof would just be wrong.... but that's not the case.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually I think if we actually calculated $2n + \frac 9n < 9+\frac 3{n^2}$ thoroughly and not just be taking limits we'd get $n< \frac 12(3 + 3^{\frac 13} + 3^{\frac 23}) \approx 3.26$.  Interesting if we consider real values we *do* get $x^3 > 3^x$ for $-\frac{3W(-\frac {\ln 3}3)}{\ln 3}\approx 2.38 < x < 3$ (where $W$ is the lambert function).. Example $2.5^3 =15.625> 3^{2.5}\approx 15.588$

Comment: $3^x =x^3$ will have a solution at $w =3$ of course but there will also be a second value and $x=w< 3$ for some real $w$.  it's easy to take points and realize $2 < w < 3$.  so $x^3 > 3^x$ for $2< w<x<3$ and $3^w=w^3$ and $3^3=3^3$ but $x^3 < 3^x$ everywhere else (which include all other natural numbers). But that abandons number theory entirely and goes into analysis.

Comment: @fleablood Another example from the MIT series hold some clue to this problem (also there is a hint in this problem suggesting Verify for n <= 4 by explicit calculation.). I am inexperienced, but I tried this way: Prove cases 1 to 4 explicitly (use calculator to verify) and show that least element m in the set of counterexamples C > 4. Then take m-4 which lies outside C (as m is the least element in a set of +ve integers) and write m-4 <= 3^(m-4)/3. Add 4 to both sides and we have m < 4 + 3^(m-4)/3. Adding 4 to a +ve number gives a number g.t. 4, so we have a contradiction.
Is this correct?

Comment: this is the [problem set](https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/assets/courseware/v1/432a6320bb11c2bfba8ed2a47e68f86d/asset-v1:OCW+6.042J+2T2019+type@asset+block/MIT6_042JS15_ps1.pdf) (for those who are interested) and [postal example video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1HpgnWQI7I)

Answer (score 3):

$n\le 3^{n/3}$ is true for $n=1$ because $\sqrt[3]{3}>1$

It is true for $n=2$, too, because $\sqrt[3]{3^2}\approx 2.08>2$

Now suppose that $3^{n/3}\ge n$ is true for $n$ and let's prove it for $n+1$

$3^{(n+1)/3}=3^{n/3}\cdot \sqrt[3]{3}\ge \sqrt[3]{3}n>n+1$. Proved.

$\sqrt[3]{3}n>n+1$ because $\sqrt[3]{3}n-n\approx 0.44n>1$ for any $n>2$

Comment: Thanks, @Raffaele for the quick and clear answer. Although I like your answer I'm not sure it can be considered a proof by the well ordering principle. I have no formal education on maths and I'm basing myself on MIT's OCW Math for computer science text book where the proofs by the WOP follow a format where in the end it have to be proved by a contradiction, being the m not the least element or being the theorem true for m. What do you think?

Comment: @Jonathan Beber I hope things go well with your self-teaching of maths. Also, this answer uses induction, and you might learn that the principle of induction is equivalent to the well-ordering principle.

Comment: Thank you very much @BenjaminWang, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I already accepted [@fleablood's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3979313/809334). I'd just like to share my own proof after some work on it as further reference for other people working on this problem.

Theorem: $n \leq 3^{n/3}\text{ for }n \geq 0$

Proof:

Let C be the set of counterexamples to the theorem, namely
$$C ::= \{n \in \mathbb{N} | n > 3^{\frac{n}{3}}\}$$

For the purpose of a contradiction, assume $C$ is not empty. By the Well-ordering principle, there's a least element, $c \in C$. The $c$ element can't be:

- 1, because $1<3^\frac{1}{3}$;
- 2, because $2<3^\frac{2}{3}$;
- 3, because $3=3^\frac{3}{3}$;
- 4, because $4<4^\frac{4}{3}$.

Therefore, $c>4$.

If $c$ is the least counterexample for the theorem, $c-1$ must hold true, once it's less than $c$ itself. So:

$$
c-1 \leq 3^\frac{c-1}{3}\\
c-1^3 \leq 3^{c-1}\\
c-1^3 \leq (3^c)(3^{-1})\\
c-1^3 \leq \frac{3^c}{3}\\
3(c-1)^3 \leq 3^c\\
$$

$c \in C$, therefore, $c > 3^{\frac{c}{3}}$:
$$
c > 3^{\frac{c}{3}}\\
c^3 > 3^c\\
3^c < c^3
$$

So, we can state that $3(c-1)^3 \leq 3^c < c^3$ and that $3(c-1)^3 < c^3$. Now, by manipulation:

$$
3(c-1)^3 < c^3\\
3(c^3-3c^2+3c-1) < c^3\\
3c^3-9c^2+9c-3 < c^3\\
2c^3-9c^2+9c-3 < 0\\
2c^3+9c < 9c^2+3\\
$$
Dividing both sides by $c^2$, we get:
$$
2c+\frac{9}{c}<9+\frac{3}{c^2}\\
$$
As stated  before, $c>4$, so:
$$
c>4\\
c^2>16\\
\frac{1}{c^2}<\frac{1}{16}\\
\frac{3}{c^2}<\frac{3}{16}\\
9+\frac{3}{c^2}<9+\frac{3}{16}\\
9+\frac{3}{c^2}<9.1875<10\\
9+\frac{3}{c^2}<10
$$

Back to the main inequality:

$$
2c+\frac{9}{c}<9+\frac{3}{c^2}<10\\
$$
Since $c \in \mathbb{N}$, we can assume $2c < 2c+\frac{9}{c}$:
$$
2c<2c+\frac{9}{c}<9+\frac{3}{c^2}<10\\
2c<10\\
c<5
$$

$c \in \mathbb{N}$, $c>4$ and $c<5$ is a contradiction and therefore $C$ must be empty. The theorem is true.

QED